# Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, error-handling, compiler-errors

Before, my program run well. But When I just updated my Android studio to the latest version (2.2 built on 15-sept-16), I am having the following error. When I built it, it says: Built sucessfully, but this error appears when I run my program:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                            Process: com.example.androidtutorial, PID: 28293
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider
>   com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.androidtutorial-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.androidtutorial-2/lib/x86,
>   /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5814)
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5403)
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5342)
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1528)
>                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
>                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
>                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.androidtutorial-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.androidtutorial-2/lib/x86,
>   /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
>                                                                                at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>                                                                                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
>                                                                                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5799)
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5403) 
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5342) 
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1528) 
>                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
>                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
>                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)

I already looked at other questions but the problem is not the same. 
What am I doing wrong? Please help

Comment: check instant run enable if yes then, disable instant run.

Comment: just follow this answer , I think it will solve your issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/44603205/6869491

Answer (score 10):

It seems you have a problem with Over 64K Methods and then tried to resolved it with `multiDexEnabled true` in build.gradle (app module). But you need to add more than:

1. add: `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'` in dependencies of build.gradle
2. Extends your Application class to MultiDexApplication. and add `MultiDex.install(this);` in `onCreated` method of Application class.

your issue should be resolved

refer link: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

Answer (score 2):

This works great which you add multidex support in manifest, when ever i encounter problem i got it fixed this way more over 64K.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp">
    <application
            android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2):

just remove the google play services dependencies if you are including it. I am able to fix this error everytime using this. If you are using google maps or any other specific google service then include the dependency for that particular service only. Also try to check the version of google play service dependency.

Answer (score 2):

**app=>build.gradle**

```
android {
.....
defaultConfig {
......
 multiDexEnabled true//add this line
}
......
dependencies{
 compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'//add this line
}
```

**In manifest**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
....
<application
....
 android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" 
...>
 <activity   />
...

</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. I resolved it by :

1) Removing unnecessary packages  in the build.gralde.

2) Disabling the Firebase plugin

3) Upgrading the build tool to the latest

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and resolved it using:

1. Clean/Rebuild your Project.
2. Restart Android Studio.
3. Update all SDK tools and Android Studio.
4. Clear Cache and Clear Data on Device.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution that works for me after trying all of these solution is by deleting **outputs** folder under **project\app\build\** and rebuilding project will let it to running state.

Answer (score 0):

Add following line to Manifest.xml

```
 <application
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
```

Add this sn App level build.gradle file

```
 defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
} 
      ......

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```