# How to fix android 4.4.2 error ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList

Tags: android, firebase, android-4.4-kitkat

```
AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.info.app, PID: 24503
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.info.app-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.info.app-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
      at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5236)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4827)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4710)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:174)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1367)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.info.app-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.info.app-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
      at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:67)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5221)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4827) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4710) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:174) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1367) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven() {
        url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
    }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }

}

android {
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
        applicationId "com.info.app"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 16
        versionName "1.0.12"
        testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            debuggable false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':CustomBrowser-release')
    compile project(':PayU-release')
    compile project(':sdkui')

    compile('com.github.worker8:tourguide:1.0.17-SNAPSHOT@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:2.3.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    compile 'com.soundcloud.android:android-crop:1.0.1@aar'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.4'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.15.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.4'
    compile 'com.nononsenseapps:filepicker:3.1.0'
    compile 'com.ufreedom.uikit:FloatingViewLib:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:4.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.2.4'
    compile 'com.stripe:stripe-android:3.1.1'
    compile 'com.braintreepayments:card-form:3.0.5'
    compile 'com.daimajia.numberprogressbar:library:1.4@aar'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

MyApplication.java:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

      @Override
      public void onCreate() {
          MultiDex.install(getApplicationContext());
          super.onCreate();
```

androidmanifest.xml:

```
<application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme">
```

Only app unfortunately stopped Android below 4.4.

Latest log file:

```
06-17 16:50:36.955 586-586/? I/SELinux: Function: selinux_android_load_priority [0], There is no sepolicy file.

06-17 16:50:37.005 586-586/? I/SELinux: Function: selinux_android_load_priority , spota verifySig and checkHash pass. priority version is VE=SEPF_GT-I9192_4.4.2_0055

06-17 16:50:37.005 586-586/? I/SELinux: selinux_android_seapp_context_reload: seapp_contexts file is loaded from /data/security/spota/seapp_contexts
06-17 16:50:37.005 586-586/? E/dalvikvm: >>>>> Normal User
06-17 16:50:37.005 586-586/? E/dalvikvm: >>>>> com.info.app [ userId:0 | appId:10286 ]
06-17 16:50:37.005 586-586/? D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
06-17 16:50:37.415 586-586/com.info.app D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
06-17 16:50:37.415 586-586/com.info.app W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41ea2da0)
06-17 16:50:37.415 586-586/com.info.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.info.app, PID: 586
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.info.app-3.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.info.app-3, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
      at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5236)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4827)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4710)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:174)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1367)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.info.app-3.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.info.app-3, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
      at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:67)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5221)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4827) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4710) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:174) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1367) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Your app needs multidex support. just add support and it ll be fine

Comment: @BabulPatel i'm added still getting error.

Comment: You might eliminate the need for Multidex by replacing the dependency on `com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.4`  with the specific Google Play services APIs you need.  See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40635422/4815718

Comment: Turn off the instant run and do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44603205/2637067. (turning off the instant run is so important)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Note: If your project is configured for multidex with minSdkVersion 20 or lower, and you deploy to target devices running Android 4.4 (API level 20) or lower, Android Studio disables Instant Run.**

When running on versions prior to **Android 5.0 (API level 21)**, using multidex is not enough to work around the linearalloc limit [(issue 78035).](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37008143) This limit was increased in **Android 4.0 (API level 14)**, but that did not solve it completely. And on versions lower than Android 4.0, you might reach the linearalloc limit before reaching the DEX index limit. So if you are targeting API levels lower than 14, test thoroughly on those versions of the platform, because your app might have issues at startup or when particular groups of classes are loaded.    [Code shrinking](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html) can reduce or possibly eliminate these issues.

You have too many methods. There can only be 65536 methods for dex.

So, enable multidex as following:

```
android {    
defaultConfig {
    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}  
}
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

**create one class like this**

```
public class Multi_Dex extends Application {
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
}
```

**now in your manifiest file add this**

```
<application
    android:name=".Multi_Dex"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

to solve this problem s, like described on this link : [developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html)

**or try this my friend for kitkat or lower version**

```
android {
defaultConfig {
    ...
    multiDexEnabled true
}
productFlavors {
    dev {
        // Enable pre-dexing to produce an APK that can be tested on
        // Android 5.0+ without the time-consuming DEX build processes.
        minSdkVersion 21
    }
    prod {
        // The actual minSdkVersion for the production version.
        minSdkVersion 14
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                                             'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

Comment: @AMahaRaja add this depedencie in your gradle filer compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'

Comment: @AMahaRaja at which line your exption throws

Comment: updated latest log file . app not open suddenly stopped https://stackoverflow.com/q/44603154/4387738

Comment: @AMahaRaja just disable your Instant run than try it sure help you

Comment: than please read documentation  https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html because there is another way to enabled multiplex for Android 4.4 (API level 20) or lower,

Answer (score 0):

add this to build.gradle, multidex is not required while you don't need multidex feature

```
dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
}
```