# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'. >

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-multidex

I created a simple hello world project but I am getting the following error:

```
Error: Execution failed for task '`:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug`'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1.
```

I have added `multiDexEnabled true` in **build.gradle** but it is still showing the above error.

My **build.gradle** file:-

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.bliss76.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true


    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java finished with non-zero exit value 2 - Android Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29756188/java-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-2-android-gradle)

Comment: paste your gradle file and multidex code

Comment: try this way to enable multidex
follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44603154/how-to-fix-android-4-4-2-error-classnotfoundexception-didnt-find-class-com-go/44603205#44603205)

Comment: @NileshRathod its simple hello world application it should started without any modifiaction

Comment: @AnamikaChavan please follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29045129/android-java-exe-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-1

Comment: Try with update java from 7 to 8 and set path properly and try again.

Comment: @Nilesh It worked for me.Just updated my jdk.

Comment: good than enjoy@AnamikaChavan

Answer (score 0):

Have you remembered to change the manifest?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.myapp">
<application
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >
    ...
</application>
```

Read more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#mdex-gradle).

Answer (score 0):

Try with attach in dependencies

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
```