# Android butterknife multidex

Tags: java, android, butterknife

I have enabled miltidex in my app. Api 21+ works fine.
Android api 16 causes:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ......AuthorizationController
```

If i comment BN binding everything works fine.
Multidex enabled: `multiDexEnabled true, compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'` and so on.
Is there any way to make it work?

**EDIT**

gradle

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        }

        dependencies {
            classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        }
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }


    android {
        signingConfigs {
            prod_release {
...
            }
        }
        compileSdkVersion 25
        buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
        productFlavors {
            dev {
                // Enable pre-dexing to produce an APK that can be tested on
                // Android 5.0+ without the time-consuming DEX build processes.
                minSdkVersion 16
                signingConfig signingConfigs.prod_release
            }
            prod {
                // The actual minSdkVersion for the production version.
                minSdkVersion 16
                signingConfig signingConfigs.prod_release
            }
        }
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "ru.wearemad.gravo"
            targetSdkVersion 25
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            multiDexEnabled true
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        dexOptions {
            javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
            preDexLibraries = false
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                signingConfig signingConfigs.prod_release
            }
            debug {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.prod_release
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs'
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
        //retrofit
        compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
        compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'
        compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
        compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.0'
        //rxjava 2
        compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
        compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.1'
        //butterknife
        compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.7.0'
        annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.7.0'
        //mosby + conductor
        compile 'com.bluelinelabs:conductor-support:2.1.4'
        compile 'com.hannesdorfmann.mosby3:mvp-conductor:3.0.0'
        compile 'com.hannesdorfmann.mosby3:viewstate:3.0.4'
        compile 'com.hannesdorfmann.mosby3:viewstate-conductor:3.0.0'
        compile 'com.madgag.spongycastle:core:1.54.0.0'
        compile 'com.madgag.spongycastle:prov:1.54.0.0'
        compile 'com.madgag.spongycastle:pkix:1.54.0.0'
        compile 'com.madgag.spongycastle:pg:1.54.0.0'
        //    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
        compile 'com.orhanobut:hawk:1.+'
        compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
            transitive = true;
        }
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    }
```

Manifest's part:

```
<application
        android:name="ru.wearemad.gravo.MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Application class:

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication {...}
```

I have tried to add `multiDexKeepProguard`, but gradle doesnt see that method, or method's declaration has changed.

**EDIT 2**
Butterknife `Unbinder` which is returned in `Bitterknife.bind(`) makes the trouble. Any ideas how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

> Have you included following?
>   If you do not override the Application class, edit your manifest file to set android:name in the  tag as follows:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp">
    <application
            android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

> if you do override the Application class but it's not possible to change the base class, then you can instead override the attachBaseContext() method and call MultiDex.install(this) to enable multidex:

```html
public class MyApplication extends SomeOtherApplication {
  @Override
  protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
     super.attachBaseContext(base);
     MultiDex.install(this);
  }
}
```

[Further read](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html)

Comment: i have tried these ways: tried my own application class which extends MultiDexApplication and super.attachBaseContext(base);
     MultiDex.install(this); too

Comment: And registered it in Manifest? <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"/>

Comment: Intresting ... try clean project and rebuilt

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: **If your project is configured for multidex with minSdkVersion 20 or lower, and you deploy to target devices running Android 4.4 (API level 20) or lower, Android Studio disables Instant Run.**

for more info [read doc](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html)

[check my ans it can help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44603154/how-to-fix-android-4-4-2-error-classnotfoundexception-didnt-find-class-com-go/44603205#44603205)

Answer (score 0):

Did you create own Application class, which extends `MultiDexApplication`? They have two variants to add multidex support. This variant with extending works well, but the variant, where you need call `MultiDex.install(this);` in `attachBaseContext`does not work.

Comment: Can you share the code of Gradle file, Manifest and Application? If will help us to better understand what is going on.