# Strange ClassNotFoundException errors

Tags: android

I have a live Android application and I see the following error in the Google Play crash reports since I have implemented multi-dexing.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass

java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication (LoadedApk.java:516)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:4703)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600 (ActivityThread.java:175)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1368)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:146)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5602)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Method.java)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:515)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1283)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1099)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (NativeStart.java)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:67)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:497)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:457)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication (Instrumentation.java:981)
  at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication (LoadedApk.java:511)
```

There is no information about which class cannot be loaded so I do not know what the problem is and how to fix it. Can someone help?

Note that the error happens on a small percentage of users on devices running Android 4.x and 5.x. Multidex is configured properly and the application works fine on emulators and actual devices we are using, as well as on most of the users' devices. We have tried reproducing the error without success so it seems to be happening under specific situations that depend on certain devices.

Comment: Can you share the code of your build.gradle and AndroidManifest.xml files ?

Comment: Multidex is configured properly since the application works fine on 99.9%+ of the devices. The error happens on a very small percentage of the users (less than 0.1%) but still I would like to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

**i think you forgot this add this in your manifest file** `android:name=".MultidexClass"` like this

```
<application
    android:name=".MultidexClass"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

for more information read this  [my ans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44603154/how-to-fix-android-4-4-2-error-classnotfoundexception-didnt-find-class-com-go/44603205#44603205)

Comment: Thanks for the note. Unfortunately, this is not a multidex setup issue (as far as I can tell) because the application works well on 99,9%+ of users devices (as well as on all devices and emulators we have tested until now). Any other ideas? Why don't we get information about the class that is not found in the Google Play crash logs?