# getting Multidex error native android after adding firebase

Tags: android, firebase

Logcat output:

```
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
     Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define 
     Lcom/google/firebase/iid/zzc;

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForStagingDebug'.

 com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/firebase/iid/zzc;
```

Here is my build.Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}
}

apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
android {

}

useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "app.test.test”
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23

    versionCode 101
    versionName “1.2.5”

    multiDexEnabled true

    resConfigs "en"
 }

 dataBinding {
    enabled true
 }

 sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
        res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets']
    }
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/java/'
    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
    release.setRoot('build-types/release')
 }

  android {
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        preDexLibraries true
        maxProcessCount 8
    }

    aaptOptions {
        cruncherEnabled false
    }
}

 buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.app_release
    }

    debug {
        debuggable true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.app_release
    }
}

productFlavors {
    production {
        minSdkVersion 15
        applicationId "app.test.test"
        resValue "string", "app_name", "test"
        resValue "string", "content_authority", "app.test.test.sync.StubContentProvider"
        resValue "string", "account_type", "test.com"
        dimension "mode"
    }

configurations {
    all*.exclude module: 'gson'
}
}

repositories {
def androidHome = System.getenv("ANDROID_HOME")
mavenCentral()

maven { url "$androidHome/extras/android/m2repository/" }

maven { url "https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com" }

maven { url "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/layerhq/releases-android/master/releases/" }

maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }

maven { url 'https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/jp-build-packages/ec-android-sdk' }

maven { url "https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/godel-release/godel/" }

maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

maven { url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/repo.commonsware.com" }

maven {
    url 'https://maven.google.com'
}
}

dependencies {
provided fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
annotationProcessor files('libs/butterknife-6.1.0.jar')
implementation files('libs/butterknife-6.1.0.jar')
implementation files('libs/retrofit-1.9.0.jar')

// segment - analyti

//crashlytics
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.6@aar') {
    transitive = true
}

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.2.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.2.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
//multidex lib
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
implementation 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
implementation 'com.felipecsl:gifimageview:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.3.0'
implementation 'fr.avianey.com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'
implementation 'net.the4thdimension:poly-picker:1.0.11'
implementation 'com.navercorp.pulltorefresh:library:3.2.3@aar'
implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.0'
//play service
implementation ('com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.4'){
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
}
implementation ('com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.4'){
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
}
implementation ('com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.2.4'){
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
}
implementation ('com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.2.4'){
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
}

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:10.2.4'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.4'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.4'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.4'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-
analytics:10.2.4'

implementation project(':PlaceAutoComplete')
implementation files('libs/gson-2.8.0.jar')
implementation 'com.oguzdev:CircularFloatingActionMenu:1.0.2'
}
apply plugin: "com.google.gms.google-services"
```

I know there are many libraries but it was working properly, suddenly it throwing me an error of Multiple dex. I have updated my Sdk platform and Sdk tool but still not working.

I know there are many libraries but it was working properly, suddenly it throwing me an error of Multiple dex. I have updated my Sdk platform and Sdk tool but still not working.

I know there are many libraries but it was working properly, suddenly it throwing me an error of Multiple dex. I have updated my Sdk platform and Sdk tool but still not working.

Comment: check this ans it may help you my friend https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44603154/how-to-fix-android-4-4-2-error-classnotfoundexception-didnt-find-class-com-go/44603205#44603205

Comment: Still not working

Answer (score 2):

**Configure multidex as following:**

```
android {    
    defaultConfig {
        // Enable multidex support for android versions grater than API 21
        multiDexEnabled true
    }  
}

dependencies {
    // Enable multidex support for android versions lower than API 21
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

**Extend Application class like this for android versions lower than API 21:**

```
public class MultiDexApp extends Application {
    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
}
```

**Now in your manifest file add your application class:**

```
<application
    android:name=".MultiDexApp" <!-- enable application class -->
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

**Note: If your project is configured for multidex with minSdkVersion 20 or lower, and you deploy to target devices running Android 4.4 (API level 20) or lower, Android Studio disables Instant Run.**

More details on this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html).

Comment: in which android version you are running this app

Comment: Same issue. Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define 
     Lcom/google/firebase/iid/zzc

Comment: minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 23

Comment: @user3606902  disables Instant Run. than run

Comment: share your gradle app file with question