# MultiDex Support issues Android

Tags: android, gradle, android-multidex

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
 com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pre-dex 'C:\Users\faisal\.android\build-cache\b8fc169a71d6759757864b00f302f95b66921263\output\jars\classes.jar' to 'C:\Users\faisal\Desktop\application-app-search-global\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dex\debug\folders\1000\10\classes_abbf8d2bb1ffecc7fb77ef565c2873fc6625cf3d'
```

Comment: check this  [enable multidex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44603205/7666442)

Answer (score 0):

**enable multidex as following:**

```
android {    
    defaultConfig {
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }  
}
dependencies {
    // add dependencies for multidex
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

**create one class like this**

```
public class Multi_Dex extends Application {
    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context context) {
        super.attachBaseContext(context);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
}
```

**now in your manifiest file add this**

```
<application
    android:name=".Multi_Dex" <!-- this line enable multi-dex application -->
    android:allowBackup="true" <!-- rest of them doesen't matter to enable multi-dex -->
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

for more detail [click here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html)

Comment: Hey I have written all that you mentioned but inspite I still keep getting the same erro. Please see my gradle.build script:

Comment: android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'hello'
            keyPassword 'hello123'
            storeFile file('D:/hello_key.jks')
            storePassword 'hello123'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
    lintOptions {
    }
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hello.asdf"
        minSdkVersion 15
        multiDexEnabled true
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 100
        versionName '1.0.4100' }

Comment: in witch  android version you are running your application

Comment: I am running it on Android 6.0 Marshmallows

Comment: add your gradlle app file with question

Comment: can u share what the problem

Comment: The problem was that application kept crashing without appropriate error messages. On the logcat it displayed error msg: "MultiDex support library disabled". But the actual issue was the plugin version of google's gsm play services.

Answer (score 0):

There was no issue with MultiDex library support. The main problem was with version of google.gms play-services.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.1'
```

which made the app to crash. All I had to was to update my google services via the android sdk manager. Then change the version number from 11.0.1 to 11.0.4. This was just the plugin version issue which crashed the app and muddled error messages.