# Getting ClassNotFoundException in runtime, unable to find activity in dexpathlist

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-multidex

Here's a list of things I have tried:

1. Disabled Instant Run (It was disabled before, since I don't use it anyways)
2. Cleaned and rebuilt my project
3. Checked name of project is the same everywhere
4. multiDexEnabled is set to true
5. [Followed all steps shown in this link](https://medium.com/@nhancv/android-deal-with-multidex-fix-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-8daf4d2135af)
6. Invalidate cache & restart
7. Created a new project and copied code from previous project

Before adding the MultiDexApplication line in Manifest I got the following stacktrace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.prajjwal.myfreight_0, PID: 27367
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.prajjwal.myfreight_0/com.prajjwal.myfreight_0.Splash}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.prajjwal.myfreight_0.Splash" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.prajjwal.myfreight_0-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2486)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2656)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1512)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5692)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
               Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.prajjwal.myfreight_0.Splash" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.prajjwal.myfreight_0-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
                  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1074)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2463)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2656) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1512) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5692) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754) 
                Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.prajjwal.myfreight_0.Splash
                  at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
                  at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                        ... 13 more
               Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

After adding that line I'm getting this:

```
12-30 16:44:12.980 5272-5272/prajjwal.com.myfreight E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                  Process: prajjwal.com.myfreight, PID: 5272
                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/prajjwal.com.myfreight-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
                                                                      at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:572)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4883)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:178)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1573)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5692)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/prajjwal.com.myfreight-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
                                                                      at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                                                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:988)
                                                                      at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:567)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4883) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:178) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1573) 
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5692) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754) 
                                                                    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication
                                                                      at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                                                      at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
                                                                      at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
                                                                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                                                                            ... 13 more
                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

I'm at my wits end and would appreciate any help.

EDIT: First stacktrace is from the old project and second one is from the new one I created

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "prajjwal.com.myfreight"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

dexOptions {

    javaMaxHeapSize "5120"
}

afterEvaluate {
    tasks.matching {
        it.name.startsWith('dex')
    }.each { dx ->
        if (dx.additionalParameters == null) {
            dx.additionalParameters = ['--multi-dex']
        } else {
            dx.additionalParameters += '--multi-dex'
        }
    }
}

subprojects {
    project.plugins.whenPluginAdded { plugin ->
        if ("com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin".equals(plugin.class.name)) {
            project.android.dexOptions.preDexLibraries = false
        } else if ("com.android.build.gradle.LibraryPlugin".equals(plugin.class.name)) {
            project.android.dexOptions.preDexLibraries = false
        }
    }
}
 }

 dependencies {

/*implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'*/
compile files('libs/jtds-1.2.8-a46da18a7c06f34fb19c38538665cbe1.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:25.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'
compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
compile 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
/*testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'*/
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44603205/7666442

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33430306/3395198

Comment: Please post your build.gradle

Comment: where is the build.gradle file?

Comment: do you have the same app installed on your emulator or phone?

Comment: Yes I have it on my phone

Comment: @Nilu I'm getting same error but with `Multi_Dex` in the stacktrace

Comment: @PrajjwalSrivastav for test case make your `"compileSdkVersion 26.0.0"`

Comment: @Nilu Please add the your comment as an answer, I'll mark it as correct. My app is working now. Thank you.

Comment: @PrajjwalSrivastav happy to help you my friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
compileSdkVersion "26.0.0"
buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
```

instead of this

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
```