# why upgrading firestore version to 17.1.0 makes a problem in the Multidex?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-multidex

my app was working fine while i was using firestore version 11.8.0 but there was always a warning regarding the firestore version it asks me to upgrade the latest version 17.1.0
after upgrading the version,the application show errors, and the android studio keeps telling me 
`//Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file. Try supplying a main-dexlist.`
I don't know why is the version of firebase storage has to do with the Multidex?
here is my build gradle.

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.moham.trial"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0-rc02'

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-rc01'


implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0-rc02'

implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.0'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Share your **`build.Gradle`** with question

Comment: you can check it now, i have updated the question with the build gradle, thx

Comment: test case try with **`27.1.1`** instead of **`28.0.0-rc02`**

Comment: just tried it now, same error

Comment: Use `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'`

Comment: I am using it already check.

`dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
        classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:8.8.1'
        
    }`

Comment: have u tried `multiDexEnabled true` https://stackoverflow.com/a/44603205/7666442

Comment: it will fix the problem the same way as using the old version of firestore 11.8.0, my main concern is **I don't know why is the version of firestore has to do with the Multidex?** I mean does that happen randomly or each time i will use the new version of firestore i have to do what u mentioned before as a solution? in other words did they do that intentionally or is it a random problem that appears with me?
btw thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: welcome you can post your solution as an answer so it can help other

Answer (score 1):

Building an android app compiles the app into bytecode (executable code) in the form of a DEX file. The compiled bytecode files (DEX files) only support 64K (65,536) methods before having to split into DEX files.

Adding the firestore library adds a lot of methods and causes this limit to be exceeded and so multiDexEnabled true is required to allow it to split into multiple files.

You can find more information at: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex