# Unable to merge Dex error: Android Studio 3.0

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle, runtime-error, dex

I've tried again and again to fix this problem, but none of the solutions proposed in the other questions worked for me. After merging my code with my teammates' code, I haven't been able to run my app due to this bug. I've cleaned and rebuilt my project multiple times, but the error still keeps coming up:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

I've tried fixing gradle warnings, updating gradle compile library statements, and putting this flag in my default config:

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

The only fix that produced something different was the above flag, which allowed me to actually run the app, but then a different run-time error occurs:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                    Process: com.example.aaronliang.flow_v1, PID: 11780
>                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider >com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: >java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class >"com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip >file "/data/app/com.example.aaronliang.flow_v1->177.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app->lib/com.example.aaronliang.flow_v1-177, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

Here are my current gradle build files:

Project build:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'

        //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        //classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

App build:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        applicationId "com.example.aaronliang.flow_v1"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.github.woxthebox:draglistview:1.5.0'
    //compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.2'
    compile 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '25.3.1'
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, because this project's due soon!

Comment: fustrating error , any body  have a solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I managed to fix my problem! I had to add these two lines:

In app/gradle.build:

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

In Manifest file:

```
android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
```

I obtained this from this question:

[Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39812558/didnt-find-class-com-google-firebase-provider-firebaseinitprovider)

Answer (score 0):

Your minSdk is lower than 20, so you have to add `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'` to your build.gradle `dependencies`.
[Source](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html)

Comment: Invalidate Caches/Restart or clean and rebuild after adding the line didn't help? Try adding this to your `android` tag: `dexOptions {
javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}`. Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41444469 ?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does that tag do?

Comment: It sets your maximum available memory to your JVM, 4g means 4 GB.